# Scatter Plot Assistance

Tags: self-study, scatterplot

I am comparing two group test scores with a scatterplot but I do not understand the scatter plot. What is the relationship between X & Y and is the test reliable? It looks almost like a short legged backward question mark.

[image: Figure]

I am trying to understand what the scatterplot is telling me. I am working on an assignment where I have created a scatterplot with test scores from a 30 point test given a month apart from each other. I am trying to compare both of the scores and see if they can tell me if this test is a reliable one. But I do not understand what I am looking at. It seems to have a negative value but that is about all I can see.

just did a bit more research and if I am understanding things it looks like I have a correlation coefficient of approximately .90 and the relationship is both positive and linear. So if I am understanding things correctly this means there is a good possibility the test is a reliable one, right?

Comment: The x and y axes already dissect the data by columns B & C. The first case, A, should have an x-coordinate of 17 and y-coordinate of 15, but this point is nowhere to be found. In addition, the axes separated the variables already, you don't need two set of symbols; there should only be 14 points on the graph.

Comment: Yeah, Penguin_Knight is right. Excel sometimes has problems with scatter plots if you don't explicitly select the data. If you just select the data (B3 to C14) and then create the plot it should be fine. However, you need to add the legends yourself.

Comment: To clarify the preceding comments, this is not a scatterplot of columns B and C. Despite what the axis labels say--they are wrong--it is simply two plots of the data columns against an *index* (a relative row number). Because the sequence of rows is probably meaningless, the first axis of this plot would be meaningless, too. The first thing you have to do, then, is to create an actual scatterplot in Excel.

Comment: Okay thanks, both of you. I did that and now there are only 12 points on the graph - it is not slanted in almost a straight line to the right so it has a positive value but I do not understand how I determine the reliability of the test Here is the link to the new one (I still have to add the legends & titles but x is the first administration and y is still the second administration).  http://i.imgur.com/lxrs1In.png

Comment: I just did a bit more research and if I am understanding things it looks like I have a correlation coefficient of approximately .90 and the relationship is both positive and linear. So if I am understanding things correctly this means there is a good possibility the test is a reliable one, right?

Comment: You might see this relationship more clearly if you adjust the relative scales of your axes so that 30 units on the x-axis has the same length as 30 units on the y-axis. Then draw on that graph the line that shows the case where the results of both test administrations were the same over the entire range of scores.